# How to specify custom elements in SVG defs section using svg.js & svg.filter.js libraries?

Tags: svg, filter, svg.js

I am using svg.js to generate a dynamically-resizing control panel. I'm also relatively new to JavaScript and this project is a learning exercise, please forgive my early-stage ignorance.

I have been successful at generating the SVG and all of my visual elements within it. The roadblock I'm hitting is that I want to create a custom filter to apply to some of the elements. I have experimented with the svg.filter.js library and I can create some of the filters shown in the example documentation, but apparently there is no support for the filter I want to use, "feDropShadow" (I concede I could be wrong about this).

I have compensated by trying to insert my own custom filter code into the defs section of the SVG object using svg.js, like this:

```
myExampleDrawing.defs().element("filter").words('<feDropShadow dx="5" dy="8" stdDeviation="0.2" />');
```

This indeed adds a filter entry to the defs section of the SVG output. However, the text passed via words() gets escaped for HTML elements along the way, so appears in the output as:

```
<filter>&lt;feDropShadow dx="5" dy="8" stdDeviation="0.2" /&gt;</filter>
```

Is there a way to use words(), or some other object method, that will allow me to handle my string unescaped? Or is there a better, supported way to specify my filter using either svg.js alone or via svg.filter.js?

I have scoured as much documentation and online discussions as I can. I'm not at the skill level where I can read the library source code to figure out the answer. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Through trial and error I have half-answered my question. The filter effect feDropShadow is created in svg.filter.js like this: add.dropShadow(settings), the "fe" is removed.

However, I'd still like to know the answer to how I can output custom strings into the SVG without them being HTML-escaped automatically.

Comment: You can use the `SVG()` constructor to create your desired element `const filterNode = SVG('<feDropShadow ...>')` and append it to your filter element: `filter.add(filterNode)`

Comment: Thank you @Fuzzyma - that worked for me, and that's a nice workaround for any future updates to the SVG standard that may not yet be implemented in svg.js and related libraries. Please post your comment as the official answer so you can get the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SVG()` constructor to create your desired element `const filterNode = SVG('<feDropShadow ...>')` and append it to your filter element: `filter.add(filterNode)`